# Is google-app-engine free for small applications?

Tags: web-hosting, google-app-engine

I read somewhere that for small applications, Google App Engine is free. Now when I read their docs, it seems that even for small applications, it isn't free.

I just wanted to check here - is it free if the application is under some size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[App Engine costs nothing to get started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html). All applications can use up to 500 MB of storage and enough CPU and bandwidth to support an efficient app serving around 5 million page views a month, absolutely free. When you enable billing for your application, your free limits are raised, and you only pay for resources you use above the free levels."